Need help finding a graduate level online course in sound propagation
I am currently based in Winnipeg, Manitoba (Canada) attending the University of Manitoba. Since my masters thesis is in the realm of marine mammal acoustics, I would like to take a course focused on sound waves in fluid/ sound propagation modeling. The University does not have such a course. I am having a hard time finding a distant learning course on this subject WITHIN Canada (Western Dean's Agreement waives any tuition cost).
For reference, I am looking into Penn State online acoustics courses however I am unsure if my funding can cover tuition cost.
Any guidance would be appreciated.

Not within Canada, but the University of New Hampshire offers courses and even a certificate in acoustics. They offer their courses online.
